# Optimal pythonic way to achieve result in dictionary

Tags: python

Is there an easier way to get the result in dict3?

I need get this in dict3:

```
{'Runes': ['Ber', 'Ko'], 
 'Swords': ['Long swords', 'Short sword'], 
 'Gold': ['12','125'], 
 'Coal':[], 
 'Wood': [], 
 'Water':['21']}
```

Here is my not optimal solution:

```
dict1 = {'Runes':['Ber','Ko'],'Swords':['Long sword'],'Gold':['','12','',''], 'Coal':['','']}
dict2 = {'Swords':['Short sword'],'Gold':['125'],'Wood':['',''],'Water':['','', '21'], 'Coal':['']}
dict3 = {}

for k1 in dict1.keys():
    if k1 not in dict3.keys():
       dict3.setdefault(k1, '')

for k2 in dict2.keys():
    if k2 not in dict3.keys():
       dict3.setdefault(k2, '')

for k3,v3 in dict3.items():
    for k1,v1 in dict1.items():
        if k3 == k1:
            dict3[k3] = v1

for k3,v3 in dict3.items():
    for k2,v2 in dict2.items():
        if k3 == k2 and type(v3) == str:
            dict3[k3] = v2

for k3,v3 in dict3.items():
    for k2,v2 in dict2.items():
        if k3 == k2 and v2 not in v3 and v2 != v3:
            dict3[k3] = v3 + v2

for k3,v3 in dict3.items():
    for k2,v2 in dict2.items():
        if k3 == k2 and '' in v3:
            s = []
            for i in v3:
                if i not in ['']:
                    s.append(i)
            dict3[k3] = s
```

Comment: Which python version is your target?

Comment: +3.5 will be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (so that you don't have to check if a given key already exists in the dictionary), and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to remove the empty values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict3 = defaultdict(list)
all_dicts = [dict1, dict2]

for data in all_dicts:
    for key, values in data.items():
        values = filter(len, values)
        dict3[key].extend(values)
```